# Why does this function hang the REPL?

Tags: recursion, idris, partial-functions, totality

Chapter 9 of [Test-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) presents the following data type and `removeElem` function.

```
import Data.Vect

data MyElem : a -> Vect k a -> Type where
   MyHere  : MyElem x (x :: xs)
   MyThere : (later : MyElem x xs) -> MyElem x (y :: xs)

-- I slightly modified the definition of this function from the text.
removeElem : (value : a) -> (xs : Vect (S n) a) -> (prf : MyElem value xs) -> Vect n a
removeElem value (value :: ys) MyHere         = ys
removeElem value (y :: ys)    (MyThere later) = removeElem value (y :: ys) (MyThere later)
```

The following works:

```
*lecture> removeElem 1 [1,2,3] MyHere
[2, 3] : Vect 2 Integer
```

But, the following call is still running after a few minutes:

```
*lecture> removeElem 2 [1,2,3] (MyThere MyHere)
```

Why is this, I'm assuming, compilation so slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second case of your `removeElem` reads

```
removeElem value (y :: ys)    (MyThere later) = removeElem value (y :: ys) (MyThere later)
```

The right-hand side is exactly the same as the left-hand side; so your recursion diverges. This is why evaluation hangs.

Note that Idris would have caught this error if you declared that `removeElem` should be total:

```
total removeElem : (value : a) -> (xs : Vect (S n) a) -> (prf : MyElem value xs) -> Vect n a
removeElem value (value :: ys) MyHere         = ys
removeElem value (y :: ys)    (MyThere later) = removeElem value (y :: ys) (MyThere later)
```

which results in the compile-time error

> `RemoveElem.idr` line 9 col 0:
>
> `Main.removeElem` is possibly not total due to recursive path `Main.removeElem`

Comment: I realize there's an obvious follow-up question in "how would I fix `removeElem`'s definition", but since you are studying, I assume you want to try and figure it out yourself first.

Comment: Thanks. What does "unfounded" mean?

Comment: I originally meant that the recursion is not well-founded. But now that I think about it, maybe that's the wrong terminology to use here...

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly to make it hopefully clearer.

Comment: It seems to me that it'd be a good idea to always put `total` in front of the function's signature. Under what circumstances would you not use `total`, Cactus?

Comment: You can make `total` the default by adding `%default total` to your module (and then you need to mark your partial functions with `partial`). As for your question, you'd not use `total` if you are defining a non-total function, of course :) [The Idris book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) has some nice examples of programs that are all `total` except for a single `partial` definition to allow e.g. a server to keep accepting new requests indefinitely. The idea is that the `total`ity of all other functions ensures that any given request is handled in finite time

Comment: The consensus with a coworker of mine is that indeed it is the correct terminology that your recursion (in the original question) was not well-founded.